# which slot type should I use for any data type or we say which can accept string type data in AWS lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have created a bot using aws-lex where I created a slot and slot-type is user defined and expand with user utterances, but this is not working as expected. This slot is not accepting all utterances we enter though test channel and re-prompting the slot question again. 
Is there any way we can create a slot-type which can accept any string utterances? or any inbuilt slot-type is there which accepts all data types?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default Amazon Lex does not have any slot type to accept **any** string.

However, you can create a slot without any value for the intent and **uncheck** the required checkbox. Then in `Lambda initialization and validation hook`, just grab the input of user from `event['inputTranscript']` and assign that value to the slot.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! this helped.

Comment: what if slots are multiple?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a requirement that you want specific type for example- Car types, then you can create your custom slot Types for example- CarTypes having values - SUV, MPV, Hatchback, etc.

Amazon currently supports various types of Slots for example,number, date, time, Airport country device etc.

But, there is nothing like string or a generic one as Amazon Slot type.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try to use the AMAZON_FIRST_NAME slot type, this kind of slot should accept almost your any-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use AMAZON.AlphaNumeric, that supports alphabets, numbers and alphanumeric values